# Can't fix Capslock delay

Tags: keyboard

I have been trying to fix the capslock delay in my keyboard since I have installed ubuntu 17.10 (through a script) and I get this error when trying to fix it:

```
Warning:          No symbols defined for <AB11> (keycode 97)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <JPCM> (keycode 103)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I120> (keycode 120)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <AE13> (keycode 132)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I149> (keycode 149)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I154> (keycode 154)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I168> (keycode 168)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I178> (keycode 178)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I183> (keycode 183)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I184> (keycode 184)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <FK19> (keycode 197)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <FK24> (keycode 202)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I217> (keycode 217)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I219> (keycode 219)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I221> (keycode 221)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I222> (keycode 222)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I230> (keycode 230)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I247> (keycode 247)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I249> (keycode 249)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I250> (keycode 250)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I251> (keycode 251)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I252> (keycode 252)
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I253> (keycode 253)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Laptop hp 15-ac659TX

Thank you.

Comment: What is they keyboard connected to Usb, (wired or wireless) PS/2 AT?

Comment: It's my laptop keyboard

Comment: Look to this: https://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2009/08/msg00122.html

Comment: Thanks! It fixed the warning but still not fixing the issue with the capslock. ANy ideas?

Comment: What model of laptop is it?